# Use Nswag Console (from NPM package) in order to generate C# client

Tags: c#, code-generation, nuget-package, nswag

According to the official Nswag [command line docs](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/CommandLine) it is possible to use Nswag via NPM console package (and subsquently generate C# client using `openapi2cscontroller`):

> To use the command line tool nswag.exe (.NET 4.6+) / dotnet-nswag.dll
>   (.NET Core), choose one of the following methods:
>
> - NSwag NPM Module: Bindings for the .NET 4.6+ and .NET Core command
>     line tools (depending on installed framework/OS platform)
> - ...

Sadly, except for the link there is no further documentation in that matter. I have installed the package linked in the documentation (using `npm install nswag --save-dev`), it is however either broken or further undocumented steps are required:

```
> nswag new
> nswag : The term 'nswag' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

Comment: Try to install nswag as global: **npm i -g nswag**

Comment: @PhatHuynh thanks, installing it globally resolved the not-found issue, is there a way to keep the installation local to the solution?

Comment: So run it by: **node_modules\.bin\nswag <params>**

Comment: @PhatHuynh all resolved now - even though it turned out to be NPM usage problem, you can consider adding it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install nswag as global:

```
npm i -g nswag
```

or use local package

```
node_modules\.bin\nswag
```